# Refer to windows environment variables in IntelliJ IDEA Run Configuration VM options

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, environment-variables, java.library.path

I'm wondering if it is possible to refer to an environment variable, e.g PATH, in the VM options field in the Run Configurations window in IntelliJ IDEA like shown in the below screenshot
[image]

The above example does not work. I've tried with $PATH$ as well without any luck.

Thanks in advance.